# Micro-Ros: Package 'micro_ros_agent' not found

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am trying to install micro-ROS through the steps provided in this link: https://micro.ros.org/docs/tutorials/core/first_application_linux/
However, when I tried to run Micro-ROS Agent node

> ros2 run micro_ros_agent
> micro_ros_agent udp4 --port 8888

it gives:

> Package 'micro_ros_agent' not found

I believe that the command line (below) supposed to create micro_ros_agent package

> ros2 run micro_ros_setup create_agent_ws.sh

but since I have run it previously, it replied:

> Repo-file ros2.repos already present,
> overwriting! ....

> === ./eProsima/Micro-XRCE-DDS-Agent (git) ===
>
> Already on 'foxy' Your branch is
> behind 'origin/foxy' by 1 commit, and
> can be fast-forwarded.   (use "git
> pull" to update your local branch)

> === ./uros/drive_base (git) ===

> Already on 'master' Your branch is up
> to date with 'origin/master'.

> === ./uros/micro-ROS-Agent (git) ===

> Already on 'foxy' Your branch is up to
> date with 'origin/foxy'.

> === ./uros/micro_ros_msgs (git) ===

> Already on 'foxy' Your branch is up to
> date with 'origin/foxy'.

> All required rosdeps installed successfully

Could any one point out where is micro_ros_agent package located?

Note:

Workspace microros_ws is overlay from workspace ros2_foxy.

PC details:

OS: Ubuntu 20

ROS Distro: ROS2 Foxy

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/382329/micro-ros:-package-%27micro_ros_agent%27-not-found/) by [irsyadtc](https://answers.ros.org/users/38009/irsyadtc/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2021-07-13

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Make sure that you do:

> ros2 run micro_ros_setup create_agent_ws.sh

> ros2 run micro_ros_setup build_agent.sh

> source install/local_setup.bash

before trying to run the micro-ROS agent.

---

Originally posted by [Pablogs](https://answers.ros.org/users/62986/pablogs/) with karma: 443 on 2021-07-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [irsyadtc](https://answers.ros.org/users/38009/irsyadtc/) on 2021-07-13**:
Thanks @Pablogs, I somehow missed out "ros2 run micro_ros_setup build_agent.sh"

**Comment by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) on 2021-07-13**:
@irsyadtc if this is correct, please check the checkmark next to the answer. Thanks.